# Not able to write the data from databricks to blob storage using python

Tags: python, dataframe, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I am not able to write the data from databricks using python not pyspark  to blob storage.

I am not getting any error message

```
indices = ['COUNTRY', 'COUNTRYNUMBER', 'COUNTRYREPORTINGSITENAME']
bound_start = date.today() - pd.offsets.Week(offset, weekday=6)  
bound_end = bound_start + timedelta(days=days) 

data = query_snowflake()

result = old_model(data, bound_start, bound_end)
print(result)
result.to_csv(r'/dbfs/mnt/storageaccountname/forecastdata/filename.csv')
result['ID'] = result.index.map(str) + ',' + result['NUMBER'].map(str)
return result.set_index(indices, append=True).reorder_levels([1, 2, 3, 0])
```

Comment: Can you provide more code and any error that you are facing?

Comment: I am not getting any error  I posted code in description

Comment: So, just are you just getting an empty file? Or is it something else?

Comment: I am not  even getting empty file after executing the code, I believe it is not writing to the blob storage

Comment: Can you check if you can find any files in os.listdir('/dbfs/mnt/storageaccountname/forecastdata/'). Or is it returning empty list?

Comment: You can also try reading the file from same path, if the required data is returned, the data is written, just not to your storage account path.

Answer (score 0):

The given code should work as expected. Check if the path contains any files using `os.listdir`. Also try reading from the same path to check whether the data is written or you are getting an error.

- Another alternative is to write the file to DBFS Filestore and then move it to mount destination as shown below:

```
pdf.to_csv('/dbfs/FileStore/output.csv', index=False)

dbutils.fs.mv('/FileStore/output.csv','/mnt/repro/new_folder')
```

[image]